# How to Print Letters Out of CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

I have a client that frequently response with "snail mail" for Cases.  They want to be able to select a response letter type (they have around 50+ standard letter types they choose from) on the Case, and then at their leisure, go and print off the mailing labels, letters, and a pick list (like an actual pick list, not a CRM PickList/OptionSet) that matches the letter to the mailing label, and anything else they need to send to the customer (coupon, rebate, etc.).

Whats the best way to handle this with minimal code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they have the budget I would say buy a product specifically for this purpose. Your client will gain a significant feature set for their investment. For example; [DCP](http://www.mscrm-addons.com/Products/DocumentsCorePack) or [XperiDo](http://www.xperido.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The Newly Improved old Software  "Act" CRM Does All Letter writing to selected individuals with also allows label printing of the same group you are writing to. No Extra Costs. But you cannot buy this outright any more you have to subscribe.
Using Old Act from  2009.
Got the last purchasable software.
But now it is based on subscription only as it seems.
In my opinion very simple to operate.
Sam B